# Smartctl utility giving uncorrectable and unreadable sectors error on HDD

Tags: hard-disk, hardware, smartctl, smart

I keep receiving mails from smartctl related to unreadable and uncorrectable sectors (these are the two errors that I get:
`Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], 209 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors`
`Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], 200 Offline uncorrectable sectors`
Is there a way to fix those errors? I also did a **conveyance** smart test on the HDD (a 3TB WD Green) which failed, the **short** test passed, haven't done a **long** test though.
The first mails started at 8 uncorrectable/unreadable sectors.
Should I assume the drive will probably die soon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unreadable sectors are a major sign that the drive is on it's way out.  Drives can die without showing bad sectors beforehand, but if a drive starts showing this kind of error it's almost guaranteed that it's not long for this world.

A 'short' SMART test doesn't actually verify the entire disk, so it can miss things that a 'long' test would find.  You can try the long test to be sure, but I wouldn't trust it with any data going forward; it's better to just replace it.

Comment: I already backed up all the important data, so that shouldn't be a problem. I think I will still keep the drive until it becomes completely unusable, but only put unimportant data on it. I will also do the 'long' SMART test. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to fix those errors?

Yes: if you overwrite the unreadable sectors, they will be remapped, and will no longer be counted as “unreadable (pending)” and “uncorrectable”; they will be counted in the “reallocated sector count”.

Drives don’t remap sectors by themselves when they fail to read them, in the hope that at some point they will be able to read them again. By writing to them, you indicate that the data stored there no longer matters, so the drive can forget those sectors.